# Elegant and efficient way to traverse through edges and resolve intersections

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, graph, traversal, pseudocode

I have an array which represents adjacency matrix of a graph like this.

```
connections:Array = [0,0,1,1,
                     0,0,1,1,
                     0,0,0,1,
                     0,0,0,0];
```

Every node of the graph has a 2D point assigned to it which represents its position on a plane.
I am trying to write a function which traverses through all the edges and returns false if any of the two edges intersect. Here is my code

```
function test():boolean
{
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length ; i++)
    {
        for (j = i ; j < nodes.length ; j ++)
        {
            if (connections[i * nodes.length + j] == 1)
            {
                //we found an edge
                //This is the place where i am stuck I, can't figure out how
                //to take pairs of edges to test them for intersections
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can give the answer in any language or even pseudo code.

Note: I don't need any code for intersection algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While traversing the adjacency matrix, build an edge-centered data structure. The easiest option is a plain list of edges. Then you can iterate all previously visited edges, which will give you a complexity of O(V^2 + E^2), where V is the number of vertices and E the number of edges.

If you have potentially large graphs, you might want to use more efficient data structures, such as a BSP tree that you build on-the-fly. This will get your complexity down to O(V^2 + E log E).

Comment: I just realized that I can bring down the number of potential pairs by skipping pairs containing at least two points having same (x,y) coordinates because two edges originating from one node will never be able to intersect.